# What is the standard of the following key called?

Tags: hex, key, guid, userid

Alright, the reason I am asking is I am analyzing a software and they have used a certain type of key. I know I have seen such keys before so there must be a standard.

It looks like this:
ED19769F-D53C-49BB-B23F-CB67DF1A69B

I know this is a simple question but it is difficulty to formulate a google search string for this problem, it doesn't help that the key is totally unique.

Question: What is the standard called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks to me like a [Globally unique identifier, or *GUID*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid), and it is *meant to be totally unique*. They are sometimes used as database table primary keys when an auto-incrementing number is not appropriate. They are also used as identifiers in places like the Windows registry and as hardware device IDs.